# tough GRE subject problem

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

what is the smallest value for $n$ for which the following limit exists for all $r \geq n$?

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{x^r}{\vert x \vert^2+\vert y \vert^2}$$

I thought of using LHopitals rule but get stuck differentiating the absolute values. I wonder if there's a trick I am unaware of. So the comments are saying to rewrite as

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{x^r}{x^2+ y^2}$$

Then by LHopitals Rule (twice) I get

$$\frac{r(r-1)x^{r-2}}{4}$$

But I get stuck here.

Comment: The value of $|x|^2$ is the same as the value of $x^2$. The denominator is really just $x^2+y^2$.

Comment: Suggestion: Drop the absolute values in the denominator (which doesn't change anything) and convert to polar form.

Comment: so let $x=\cos \theta$ and $x^2+y^2=r^2$?

Comment: I think you want for $r > n$ (strict inequality)

Comment: @zugzug the problem doesn't say strict.

Comment: Does $n$ need to be a positive integer?

Comment: @zugzug yes I believe so

Comment: write in polar coordinates. Should be easy. I recommend changing the notation in the problem by writing, say, $x^t$ so it's not confused with $r$ from polar coordinates.

Comment: @HossienSahebjame My pleasure to get the source of this problem, as well as the problem No. THANKS A LOT!

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari ??

Comment: @HossienSahebjame Can you please help me to know?

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari I am uncertain, I think in the GRE problems practice booklet with the peace signs all over it the blue one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use anything like L'Hopital since this does not apply to multivariate limits. The trick, as suggested in the comments, is to switch to polar coordinates: $x=u\cos(v)$ and $y=u\sin(v)$ so that $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ is equivalent to $u \to 0$ (and $v$ left arbitrary). Then $|x|^2+|y|^2=x^2+y^2=u^2$. So our limit is now:

$$ \lim\limits_{(u,v) \to (0,v)} \dfrac{u^r\cos^r(v)}{u^2} = \lim\limits_{(u,v) \to (0,v)} u^{r-2}\cos^r(v)$$

If $r>2$, then $u^{r-2}\cos^r(v)$ is bounded by $\pm u^{r-2}$ and  since $\pm u^{r-2} \to 0$ as $u \to 0$, we have that $u^{r-2}\cos^r(v) \to 0$ as $(u,v)$ heads to the polar origin.

If $r<2$, approaching along the ray $v=0$ (i.e., the positive $x$-axis), we are left with $u^{r-2}$ which blows us. Approaching along other rays can yield other values as well. So the limit does not exist for $r<2$.

Finally at $r=2$, we have $\cos^r(v)$. Since this depends on the choice of $v$, the limit does not exist. Or you could go back to the original expression: $\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}$ and see that along the $x$-axis (i.e., $y=0$) this is 1 and along the $y$-axis (i.e., $x=0$) this is $0/(0+y^2)=0$.

In summary, the limit exists (and equals 0) exactly when $r>2$.

Comment: AHH when converting I forgot to let $x$ equal $r \cos \theta$ or in your case $u \cos \theta$, thanks!! makes so much more sense!!

Comment: Yeah, I avoided using $r$ and $\theta$ since $r$ was already being used as a parameter. :)

Comment: lol makes sense, thanks again!! :)

Comment: Now that I think of it, writing $|x|^2+|y|^2$ instead of $x^2+y^2$ and using $r$ as a parameter are kind of jerk moves to keep the problem solver from thinking of using polar coordinates.

Comment: very true!! I didn't even think to appeal to polar coordinates!

Answer (score 1):

For $r >2$, $r \in \mathbb{N}, $ $(x,y) \not=(0,0)$.

$0 \le |\dfrac{x^r}{x^2+y^2}|\le |\dfrac{x^r}{x^2}| = |x|^{r-2}$.

$r=0,1,2$ are ruled out (why?).